# Associations in Activeslick

Tags: scala, activerecord, playframework, slick

I was trying Active-Slick and was able to execute active slick example https://github.com/reactivemaster/active-slick-example

But i am not sure how to manage associations using Active-slick. Please provide example.

Also i tried to achieve it using below method but not sure is it good way of doing and is it still eligible to be called as active record pattern.

```
  BookService.scala
     val book= Book(None,"Harry Potter")
          val action = for {
            id <-  bookDao.insert(acc)
            y<-authorDao.insert(new Author(None,id,"J.K.Rowling"))
          }yield y

         db.run(action.transactionally
```

Answer (score 0):

We use UUIDs for the ID column and they are generated in the Scala code, not by the database. I don't know how this will work with your "active record pattern" but it is nice because you can associate objects all you want before having to talk to the database. I also prefer this typed `Id[T]` in favour of the individual types like `BookId` and `AuthorId`.

```
case class Id[+T](value: String) extends MappedTo[String]
case object Id {
  def generate[T]: Id[T] = Id[T](java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString)
}

case class Author(authorId: Id[Author], name: String)
case class Book(authorId: Id[Book], title: String, authorId: Id[Author])

val newAuthor = Author(Id.generate, "JK Rowling")
val newBook = Book(Id.generate, "Harry Potter", newAuthor.id)

// do other stuff?

val action = for {
  _ <- authorDao.insert(newAuthor)
  _ <- bookDao.insert(newBook)
} yield 1
db.run(action.transactionally)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for replying. As your answered that we should use UUID instead of relying on database, I have question on that. I understand UUID for random generation and there is 1 in million in chances that any no that can be repeated number but is this statement is true even  when server is restarted?

Comment: No chance. Using the cryptographic v4 generation function I have referenced (in java.util), for there to be a one in a billion chance of duplication, 103 trillion UUIDs must be generated ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Collisions)). No, the server restarting will not have any effect on this probability.

Comment: Ok.Thanks.Also while i was trying to map functions to columns specially def *, i was facing compilation error. Do you have any sample program or can you just share piece of code where we map function to table columns

Comment: Here is a simple example [gist](https://gist.github.com/retrospectacus/2c2f232337c7b68f42dee3ea92762633). It is using slick's `HList` method (to support classes with >22 fields) but I think it would work fine the [simple way](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/schemas.html#mapped-tables).